# After changing /etc/profile, what do I have to do to reset my shell?

Tags: linux, unix

To test its effects immediately instead of having to reload the terminal

Answer (score 91, accepted):

use `source /etc/profile`

for details, man source or you can checkout this link http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Source_command

Comment: It's only applicable for current shell.

Comment: And that's what Tetsujin no Oni meant, right? `what do I have to do to reset my shell`

Answer (score 14):

If this is bash you can do `. /etc/profile`, it's the same as doing `source /etc/profile`.

Answer (score 6):

As [sjr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373653/sjr) says, you can approximate the effect of the change by re-reading `/etc/profile` using the dot `.` (or, in Bash, `source`) command.

However, you need to be aware that `/etc/profile` gets to work with a more minimal starting environment, so the effect you get by rereading the profile is not necessarily identical to the effect you get on login.  You can simulate the original environment more accurately using the `env` command to unset the environment.  With `bash`, you can use the `-l` option to make the shell behave more like a login shell - in conjunction with `env`, you can simulate the login environment accurately:

```
env -i HOME=$HOME PATH=/bin:/usr/bin USER=$USER ... bash -l
```